# Switch OpenGL contexts or switch context render target instead, what is preferable?

Tags: macos, opengl

On MacOS X, you can render OpenGL to any `NSView` object of your choice, simply by creating an `NSOpenGLContext` and then calling `-setView:` on it. However, you can only associate one view with a single OpenGL context at any time. My question is, if I want to render OpenGL to two different views within a single window (or possibly within two different windows), I have two options:

1. Create one context and always change the view, by calling `setView` as appropriate each time I want to render to the other view. This will even work if the views are within different windows or on different screens.
2. Create two `NSOpenGLContext` objects and associate one view with either one. These two contexts could be shared, which means most resources (like textures, buffers, etc.) will be available in both views without wasting twice the memory. In that case, though, I have to keep switching the current context each time I want to render to the other view, by calling `-makeCurrentContext` on the right context before making any OpenGL calls.

I have in fact used either option in the past, each of them worked okay for my needs, however, I asked myself, which way is better in terms of performance, compatibility, and so on. I read that context switching is actually horribly slow, or at least it used to be very slow in the past, might have changed meanwhile. It may depend on how many data is associated with a context (e.g. resources), since switching the active context might cause data to be transferred between system memory and GPU memory.

On the other hand switching the view could be very slow as well, especially if this might cause the underlying renderer to change; e.g. if your two views are part of two different windows located on two different screens that are driven by two different graphic adapters. Even if the renderer does not change, I have no idea if the system performs a lot of expensive OpenGL setup/clean-up when switching a view, like creating/destroying render-/framebuffer objects for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I investigated context switching between 3 windows on Lion, where I tried to resolve some performance issues with a somewhat misused VTK library, which itself is terribly slow already.

Wether you switch render contexts or the windows doesn't really matter,
because there is always the overhead of making both of them current to the calling thread as a triple. I measured roughly 50ms per switch, where some OS/Window manager overhead charges in aswell. This overhead depends also greatly on the arrangement of other GL calls, because the driver could be forced to wait for commands to be finished, which can be achieved manually by a blocking call to glFinish().

The most efficient setup I got working is similar to your 2nd, but has *two* dedicated render threads having their render context (shared) and window permanently bound. Aforesaid context switches/bindings are done just once on init.

The threads can be controlled using some threading stuff like a common barrier, which lets both threads render single frames in sync (both get stalled at the barrier before they can be launched again). Data handling must also be interlocked, which can be done in one thread while stalling other render threads.

Comment: The 50 ms, do they refer to GLContext switching or render target switching? And if they refer to the first one, were the contexts shared or unshared?

Comment: The contexts were shared (mandatory), the overhead was more or less steady and came from making different pairs of windows and render contexts current, independently which one changed. This measurment can not be a general truth, since I didn't measure the switching overhead without shared data or without pending draw calls. It is possible, that you can measure differences for both of your approaches in your specific case (with or without drawing).

Comment: Well, I tried to benchmark the context switching overhead by a syntactical benchmark, using unshared contexts with only one resource (a very big texture) in each of them and with no pending drawing calls. The result was that about 50'000 context switches per second are possible. This sounds pretty hgih but must be taken with a grain of salt, since honestly, how realistic is this benchmark? Which app would have that little resources or never any pending drawing calls? So your number is probably much better than mine one, at least more realistic.

Comment: 50'000... an interesting number nonetheless! The worst case on context switching is, when the other window is 'located' on another graphics card, modified contents have to be transferred over the bus. Of course, drivers are good in lazy operation, but it happens when rendering to textures, for example, or when the texture is not stored persistently in GPU memory because of resource management. Unfortunately, I don't have access to that Mac now.

Comment: A relevant chapter: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-AsynchronousBufferTransfers.pdf